# Paperclip is not generating url properly for CNAME

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm tying to get a cloudfront distribution wired up with a custom domain to paperclip but it's not generating my url properly. Here is my configuration:

```
# initializers/paperclip_defaults.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!({
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/amazon_s3.yml",
  :bucket => "my-image-bucket",
  :path => "production/attachments/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  :url => ":s3_host_alias",
  :s3_headers => {'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=2147483648'},
  :s3_protocol => :https,
  :s3_host_alias => "cdn.mydomain.com",
})
```

According to the docs and every blog post I've read this should be correct. The problem is that it winds up generating this:

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-image-bucket/production/products/images/44/original/my-image.jpg`

The only way I've gotten it to use the CNAME is by specifying `s3_host_name` which according to the documentation is only used for the Tokyo region. And this also breaks uploads. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using `Paperclip 3.5.2`.

**UPDATE**

I'm debugging inside `attachment.rb#url` and here's what I'm seeing. `Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url]` returns `cdn.mydomain.com` which is correct. However, `@options[:url]` is returning `:s3_path_url` instead of `s3_host_alias`. For some reason that default option is not being merged in properly. However the `s3_host_alias` option is since `@options[:s3_host_alias]` is returning `cdn.mydomain.com` as expected.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that `:s3_alias_url` is the correct token to use for the url and not `:s3_host_alias`. Not sure where that's documented though. Had to look at `s3.rb` to figure it out.